# Using malloc to allocate memory dynamically, I receive an error when trying to compile in cygwin

Tags: c

I am trying to allocate memory for a 3 by 5 2-dimensional array. When compiling this code, I receive this error in the cygwin terminal:

```
2darraymalloc.c: In function 'main':
2darraymalloc.c:7:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'malloc'    a[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int *a[3], i, j;

    for (i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) {
        a[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) {
        for (j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++) {
            a[i][j] = i + 2 * j;
        }
    }

    printf("%d", *a[2]);
}
```

Comment: [Related reading](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/440558) (which also contains the solution to your problem).

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `stdlib.h`, also always check if `malloc()` did return a valid pointer, on error it returns `NULL`, and `main()` should return `int`, a valid signature for `main()` in your case could be `int main(void)`.

Always enable compilation warnings, add this to the *gcc* invocation

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -o my-program-name my-source.c
```

Comment: Thank you, the #include <stdlib.h> solved my problem

Comment: @Michael I know, that's why I told you to add it.

Comment: I was just commenting to let you know that it was just the stdlib.h, not the main function. It's fine to have void main() and not return anything

Comment: @Michale NO IT'S NOT. Please respect what I said by doing research. It's not correct to have `void main()`, not with the compiler you are using. Please enable compiler warnings and you will see. And if you intend to ignore warnings please don't write c code.

Comment: easy.. i appreciate the help regardless

Comment: Yes you should, but really try to learn things right. That would make me happier.

Answer (score 0):

In C functions that do not have a prototype defined are assumed, by default, to return `int`. Since you did not include `stdlib.h` it leaves `malloc()` undeclared and therefore assumed to return `int`. The statement `a[i] = malloc(...)` has on the left side a int pointer and on the right side an int - thus the error message.